# App is posting data Successfully, But I would like to retrieve token

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, rx-java

Am using retrofit and RxJava to Connect to API. Data is being successfully posted to Server but i would like to get the Token which the API generates after posting data.

This is for Authentication of user using a JSON Web Token Django Backend 
The models are working fine but Here are my Models:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private User_ user;

    public User_ getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User_ user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("user", user).toString();
    }

}

public class User_ {

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("email", email).append("password", password).toString();
    }

}
```

```
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private LoginResponse_ user;

    public LoginResponse_ getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(LoginResponse_ user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("user", user).toString();
    }

}

public class LoginResponse_ {
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("email", email).append("token", token).toString();
    }
}
```

Retrofit Interface

```
    @POST("auth/login")
    @Headers("X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest")
    Observable<User> login(
            @Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
            @Body User user
    );
}
```

Retrofit Adapter

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static Gson gson;
    public static synchronized Retrofit getUser() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            if (gson == null) {
                gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
            }


            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
```

Retrofit Instance

```
public class NetworkUtils {
    private static UserService userService;

    public static UserService ApiInstance(){
        if (userService == null){
            userService = ServiceGenerator.getUser().create(UserService.class);
        }
        return userService;
    }
}
```

This is how am trying to login the user

```
private void loginProcess(String email, String password) {
        User user = new User();
        User_ user_ = new User_();
        user_.setEmail(email);
        user_.setPassword(password);
        user.setUser(user_);
        mUserService.login("application/json", user)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(User user) {
                        showResponse(user.toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response: "+ user);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        handleResponse();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleResponse(LoginResponse response) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreference.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,response.getUser().getToken());
        editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,response.getUser().getEmail());
        editor.apply();

        mEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        mEditTextPassword.setText(null);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

It would be really helpful if i get to know how to get response after posting the data to the API.
Using postman this is what i post

```
{"user":{"email":"user@email.com", "password":"userpassword"}}
```

And this is the response I get

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "user@email.com",
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NSwiZXhwIjoxNTY5MjI5NTgxfQ.S-1yZWNhx_TV8uay8PubGoq9XMpyTIn_ipG8A6DWTfE"
    }
}
```

Comment: i assume you are getting the token in your onNext(). you need to check the method handleResponse(). what is the exact problem you are having regarding the token?

Comment: I cant put LoginResponse in in onNext() method it only accept User model

Comment: in onNext() you are getting user. right ? can you confirm that the user object has email and token in it? what is the log you are getting in this line >> Log.i(TAG, "Response: "+ user);

Comment: Moreover, `handleResponse()` called `onNext` doesn't have any parameters, the method you provided takes a `LoginResponse `, do you have several signatures of the same method?

Comment: Yeah. The issue was that I did not put the token fields in User Model. That helped me get Response.